# How do I loop through a list like a circle?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any way that I can loop through a list like a circle? once I reach the end of the list I would simply go back to the first number?

I tried doing the pop and append method

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
lst2 = lst.pop(0)
lst2 = lst2.append(lst[0])
```

Is there a better way of doing this? I'm not allowed to use import as part of a restriction.

Comment: `lst2` isn't a list, it's the element that was popped off the list.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for` loop nested inside a `while` loop.

```
while True:
    for item in lst:
        # do something with item
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a generator with while and nested for:

```
def cycle(myList):
    while True:
        for x in myList:
            yield x
```

And loop like:

```
for item in cycle(lst):
  # do something with item
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will help:
*btw in the end it will spit "recursion error"*

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]

def fun(X):
    ls1 = []
    for itm in X:
        ls1.append(itm)
        if itm == X[-1]:
           fun(ls1)
```

Comment: cute but iteration in this case is better than recursion in this case. This really isn't a recursive problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the modulus (`%`) operator while indexing the list:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
FOREVER = 10                   # The number of times you want to print the
                               # list elements
for i in range(FOREVER):
    print (lst[i % len(lst)])  # Use the modulus operator to wrap-around
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5
```